# How to create a film strip in django using bootstrap and for loop?

Tags: django, twitter-bootstrap, django-templates

How do I display a group of 6 thumbnails in my template to create a filmstrip. The list i am iterating through a for loop has around 30 items i want to break it into chunks of 6 and show it as a filmstrip slider. I tried using the range function for the for loop but that doesnt work

```
<div class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="item active">
            <ul class="thumbnails">

              {% for show in object_list %}
                    <li class="span2">
                        <div class="thumbnail">
                             <a href="{{ show.get_absolute_url }}" data-title="{{ show.name }}" >
                                    {% if show.images.exists %}
                                        {% with show.images.all.0.image as show_image %}
                                            <img src="{% thumbnail show_image 160x160 crop %}" alt="{{show.name}}" class="thumbnail">
                                        {% endwith %}
                                    {% else %}
                                        <img src="{% static 'img/default-image.gif' %}" alt="{{show.name}}" class="thumbnail">
                                    {% endif %}
                                </a>


                        </div>
                    </li>
            {%endfor%}  
           </ul>
        </div>
```

Comment: One carousel per 6 images?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want 1 carousel per 6 images then you could do it like this

**Step 1)** Create a new .html file in your templates folder called `film-slider.html`.

```
{% for reel in reels %}
<div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="item active">
        <ul class="thumbnails">
            {% for show in reel %}
            <li class="span2">
                <div class="thumbnail">
                     <a href="{{ show.get_absolute_url }}" data-title="{{ show.name }}" >
                        {% if show.images.exists %}
                            {% with show.images.all.0.image as show_image %}
                                <img src="{% thumbnail show_image 160x160 crop %}" alt="{{ show.name }}" class="thumbnail">
                            {% endwith %}
                        {% else %}
                            <img src="{% static 'img/default-image.gif' %}" alt="{{ show.name }}" class="thumbnail">
                        {% endif %}
                    </a>
                </div>
            </li>
            {% endfor %}  
       </ul>
    </div>
</div>
{% endfor %}
```

**Step 2)** In your templatetags/tags.py (create it if you haven't)

```
from django import template

register = template.Library()

def filmslider(reel):
    reels = []
    for i in range(0, len(reel), 6):
        reels.append(reel[i:i+6])
    return {'reels':reels}

register.inclusion_tag('film-slider.html')(filmslider)
```

This will make an inclusion tag that's available in your templates once you've loaded it via `{% load tags %}`.

This will make this work for you like this `{% filmslider object_list %}` which you will replace all the above html code that **you** posted with.

*I haven't tested* this but it should work, if in the future you want to have more functionality to this tag you can simply add arguments to the tag definition, I'll give an example.

```
def filmslider(reel, slides):
    #do the code.
```

which will lead you to `{% filmslider object_list 9 %}` and voila, now you can extend your film reel from 6 slides to 9.

Hope this helps a bit!

Comment: Thank you so much, this is amazing. Also, I am new to Django, can you please tell where should I create my tempatetags directory ?

Comment: In your app module create a folder called templatetags and make sure it has an init.py inside. Its in the docs, google templatetags Django and its the first result! :)

Comment: Absolutely what I wanted, this will also help me in my future front end presentation. Thanks a ton!

Comment: I am getting an error now-  TemplateSyntaxError at /
'tagswoko' is not a valid tag library: Template library tagswoko not found, tried

Comment: Did you name your file tagswoko?

Comment: 1. File renamed to tagswoko, location templatetags/tagswoko.py
2. init added
3. added to Install app aswell
still getting the same error

Comment: Its working, just one change the inner carousel should needs to be out of the for loop. Thanks!